# Get the href value from inspect element in Python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am searching name in LinkedIn and after that I need to extract profile URL for the first result for that I need the href value by clicking inspect element.

**screen shot of inspect element** - [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ls4UI.png)

**url of the page** - https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/all/?keywords=bill%20gates&origin=TYPEAHEAD_HISTORY&position=0&searchId=5b939aaa-3ded-428a-b520-7b034fa61ba1&sid=Tjr

how to extract that link in the value of href efficiently?

I have tried extracting but failed(commented those lines at the end) -

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'chromedriver_full_path\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("linkedin_sign_in_page_url")
username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='session_key']")))
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='session_password']")))

#enter username and password
username.clear()
username.send_keys("username")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("password")
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()
#linkedin search
search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[placeholder='Search']")))
search.clear()
search.send_keys('bill gates')
time.sleep(4)
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(4)
# try 1
# elems = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".app-aware-link [href]")))
# links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elems]
# links
# try 2
# print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("p.app-aware-link > a").get_attribute('href'))
```

**my expected output** - "https://www.linkedin.com/in/williamhgates?miniProfileUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_miniProfile%3AACoAAA8BYqEBCGLg_vT_ca6mMEqkpp9nVffJ3hc"

Comment: Post the full URL of the page you are trying to scrape. Do not post screenshots

Comment: Sorry, and I have added the full url of the page in qstn, please help and let me know if you need anything else to solve

Comment: Hi @Himanshu Poddar the screenshot is already added - screenshot of inspect element - img(link of image), please check once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven,
When I tried your code, I found your CSS selector in the last line of your code did not match what I can see on the same link.
So if you Replace the following line in your code:

```
# print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("p.app-aware-link > a").get_attribute('href'))
```

with

```
print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".search-results-container a.app-aware-link").get_attribute('href'))
```

This should get the URL you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ketanvj, I was really worried as I was unable to proceed, but you helped me, thanks again, Just wanted ask, will this element work in future also?, as I have heared that these elements might change in future.

Comment: Maven, It depends on how the class names are generated. If they are generated dynamically then they may change. In this case, I do not see that is the case so it should work.

Comment: Thanks @ketanvj, but how did you determine that the class is generated dynamically? how did you figured it out?

Comment: @maven I typically try to open the same page from different browsers or refresh the page. You can try this as an example. If you can log in to your Gmail account, and click on compose button (typically on the left-hand top corner. In the inspect element - type this locator "//form[@class='bAs']". In this case, I found that even though the "class" is not dynamic but "id" is dynamic. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: @maven one more option to know is to contact developers, they should be able to tell us. And this should be our first option.